# Problemas con el onChildClick en una ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un programa y no sé por qué falla. Tengo un objeto `ExpandableListView` que hace de `Adapter` y un `Fragment` que llama a este objeto. Al los elementos de la lista, funciona, el problema está en el `onChildClick`, lo que pretendo es que al pulsar un elemento de la lista, se guarde en el `TextView` y lo muestre para utilizarlo más tarde. El problema es que solo recoge el primer elemento de la lista al pulsarlo, si pulso otro elemento, la aplicación deja de funcionar sin darme error. ¿Qué podría hacer para solucionar esto?

La clase `ExpandibleListView`:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader ;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(
        int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent
    ) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

El *Fragment*:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    //Expandable list Adapter
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    //Users
    private List <User> items = new ArrayList<>();

    //Obejeto a pasar
    User user = new User();
    String password;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //Botones
        TextPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);
        TextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
            getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild
        );

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        ExpandableListView ExList =(ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp) ;

        //Llamamos al boton fichar
        fichar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fichar);

        //Call ExpandibleList view child on pressed
        ExList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(
                ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                int childPosition, long id
            ) {
                ShowItem(listDataHeader.get(childPosition));

                TextName.setText(
                    listAdapter
                        .getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString()
                );
                return false;
            }
        });
        fichar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                password = TextPass.getText().toString();
                //SuperUsuario
                if(
                    key.equalsIgnoreCase("cesi.tic")&&
                    password.equalsIgnoreCase("123456789")
                ){
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).EditarUsuario();
                    fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    LeerFirebase();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void ShowItem(String id)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Como podéis ver en el `onChildClick`, está como creo que debería funcionar pero no es así.

Answer (score 0):

Vale ya he encontrado la solución, ya se que estaba haciendo mal, solo tengo que eliminar:

// ShowItem(listDataHeader.get(childPosition));

y ya funciona correctamente.
Espero que os ayude mi pos.

Aquí esta el resultado después de esta pequeña corrección.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                TextName.setText(listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString());

                return false;
            }
        });
```